# DOORS advanced link by attribute DXL script

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm using DOORS 9.6. I have two modules in DOORS, on that is a MIL Handbook (module 1), and the other that is a list of artifacts/data that should be linked to the MIL handbook (module 2).  I have a link module also set up between the two.  I could manually drag and drop the objects from module 2 to module 1, but that seems horribly inefficient.  I'm looking for a way to use a .csv or a list of correlating inputs (objects in modules 1&2) that could be used by the DXL script to automatically link each module.

I've tried using ChatGPT to help, and keep getting errors.  I also found a DXL script from 2008, with no joy.  HELP!

Answer (score 0):

A DXL script from 2008 should generally still work, perhaps you can post the link to the script and tell us why it did not work for you.

Otherwise: one way that works quite well "Link -> Advanced -> Link by attribute".
You can use it like this:

- Prepare a csv file with the Heading "Absolute Number,Link Destination" and add lines for the corresponding values, with the left value being the object's number of the outgoing link and the right value the number of the object in the link destination module.
- Open the module that shall contain the out links
- Create an attribute of type Text(!) with the name "Link Destination"
- use "File -> Import -> Spreadsheet" with the parameters Import to attributes: By column labels, Import options: Update existing objects, Update: All Objects and give the Input file, press Import, choose "Absolute Number" as the identifying column.
- the objects to be linked should now have the Link Destination attribute set correctly
- now use "Link -> Advanced -> Link by Attribute", choose the target and link modules,  use the attribute Link Destination for the link, choose Link direction Source to target, press OK

Comment: So it works, but I have multiple "Link Destinations" for each "Absolute number"  With this in mind, it only captures my first link destination.  Any idea on how to handle multiple instances to the same "absolute number?

Comment: Thank you so much Mike!  I figured it out.  Created an Object Heading Identifier to create multiple instances for each link.  IT WORKS!